# Logging SOAP message on http gateway spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration (4.0.6) to make SOAP calls from rest service using int-http:outbound-gateway and int-ws:outbound-gateway. Is there a way to log SOAP request message only in case of exception.

```
<int:gateway id="myGateway" service-interface="myservice">
    <int:method name="getData" request-channel="reqChannel" reply-channel="repChannel">
</int-gateway>
```

my outbound-gateway configured as below

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="og1" request-channel="reqChannel" url="xxx" http-method="POST" reply-channel="repChannel" reply-timeout="10000" message-converters="converter" request-factory="reqFactory">

<bean id="reqFactory"
     class="org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="cTimeout" value="20000"/>
    <property name="rTimeout"    value="20000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please stop defacing your post by rolling it back to an early, incomplete version. If you wish to request disassociation so your name is no longer associated with the post, please use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: i reached out (with contact us) twice yesterday to delete my post along with it's revisions. Can you please help me to remove this post's revisions and the post too. Thank you.

Comment: @HariBajavada it's the weekend. These things take longer at weekends.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Try this method. 
Create your own error Handler which implements the spring Error Handler Interface. In your context file

```
<bean id="soapErrorHandlingSyncTaskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="ErrorHandle" 
p:errorSender-ref="errorSender"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
<bean id="errorSender" class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
        p:defaultChannel-ref="errors" />
```

When ever your WS adapter throws any exception then org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor catches this exception now its upto you how you handle the exception in your error handler.

The SOAP faultcode and faultstring is found in the MessagingException's cause (if a SoapFaultClientException).

Here i am sending the error messages to a channel for me to monitor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to share some config and the point where would you like to get a log/exception.

Both, `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` and `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` have `<request-handler-advice-chain>` ability, where you could use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and send an `ErrorMessage` with the request (guilty?) message for any diagnostics.

You should configure the `readTimeout` on the appropriate `ClientHttpRequestFactory`, e.g. `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory#setReadTimeout(int timeout)`.

Regarding converters and the wish to log their results in case of error...

How about to implement `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` with the desired logic:

```
try {
   return execution.execute(request, body);
catch (Exception e) {
   this.errorChannel.send(...);
}
```

I'm prety sure that the `byte[] body` is your SOAP request.

See `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` JavaDocs for more info.

The `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` is part of `RestTemplate`, which can be injected to the `http:outbound-gateway`.

For the `ws:outbound-gateway` you should use `ClientInterceptor` with the `handleFault` implementation and extract `MessageContext.getRequest()` for your purpose.

Comment: No, do the *edit* of your question and share more info there. Or just try figure out if my answer is sufficient for you already and I can go ahead with help for other guys.

Comment: Please, move the same to your question and format properly for better readability.

Comment: On the `<int:gateway>` level you can configure `receive-timeout` and `error-channel`. See the Reference Manual for more info: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

Comment: I've just added to the answer the note about `RestTemplate`

Comment: Well, everything in your config looks like I would like to see. Not sure what is your problem... Maybe that would be better to debug it line by line to determine the proper property to extract. Although for me the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` has exactly desired `SOAP Request` to send...

Comment: The exception doesn't help here at all. Just follow with the `HttpAccessor.createRequest()` breakpoint and so on. The `request` there must be `InterceptingClientHttpRequest` where on of `interceptors` should be your `ReqInterceptor`.